# Why do Google's JS Client SDK function callbacks fail?

Tags: google-signin

I'm currently in the learning phase for how the Google JS Client SDK works, since my boss needs me to learn how to integrate a Sign In button to his site to enable people to Authenticate via Google.  I am testing the code for the custom Sign In button, with a touch of added functionality (like a Sign Out button), and in the process I've practically copy/pasted the code from their website.  Let me show you the code first and then explain the issue, so that you can understand where the code is failing:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var clientId = '{my client id here}'; // for web
    var apiKey = '{my api key here}';
    var scopes = 'profile email';

    function SignOut() {
        // I know, sloppy, but the signOut method from Google doesn't work.
        window.location = 'https://accounts.google.com/logout'; 

        // Additional code if necessary.
    };

    function makeApiCall() {
        gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function () {
            var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({ 'userId': 'me' });
            request.execute(function (response) {
                var heading = document.createElement('h4');
                var image = document.createElement('img');
                image.src = response.image.url;
                heading.appendChild(image);
                heading.appendChild(document.createTextNode(response.displayName));
                document.getElementById('name').appendChild(heading);
                alert('User logged in.  makeApiCall() has executed.');
            })
        })

    };

    function init() {
        gapi.client.setApiKey(this.apiKey);
        window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
        console.log('Up and ready to go.');
    };

    function checkAuth() {
        // Triggers when the page and the SDK loads.
        gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true }, handleAuthResult);
    };

    function handleAuthClick(event) {
        // Triggers after a user click event to ensure no popup blockers interfere.
        gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false }, handleAuthResult);
        return false;
    };

    function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('SignInBtn');
        var signoutButton = document.getElementById('SignOutBtn');

        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
            var V = JSON.stringify(authResult);
            localStorage.setItem('GoogleAuthResult', V);
            console.log(V); // Just for testing...
            var authTimeout = (authResult.expires_in - 5 * 60) * 1000; setTimeout(checkAuth, authTimeout); // As recommended by a Google employee in a video, so that the token refreshes.
            authorizeButton.style.display = 'none'; // Switching between Sign In and Out buttons.
            signoutButton.style.display = 'inline-block';

            makeApiCall();

        } else {
            // Immediate:true failed so user is NOT signed in.
            // Make the Sign In button the one visible and prep it
            // so that it executes the Immediate:false after user click:
            authorizeButton.style.visibility = 'inline-block';
            authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
            signoutButton.style.visibility = 'none';                
        }
    };
</script>
```

The **handleAuthClick** function **does run** on the button click, but after taking the user to the Google Sign In page, when that page brings me back, the browser kinda flickers and the **handleAuthResult function does not execute**.  Therefore, **nothing changes in the page after the successful sign in**; the button displayed is the Sign In button (Sign Out button not visible) and no information is displayed on the 'name' textNode.  This happens on Internet Explorer (11), Firefox (39) and Chrome (44).  Also, it happens at home on my laptop (straight connection to the web via Cable broadband) and at work (on Windows 8.1 behind an Active Directory).

I began wondering so I started refreshing the browser page and after a couple of refreshes, since the script runs from the beginning, the immediate:true fires again and voilá:  user is connected and API call triggers.

So, on my laptop, I changed the function being called back, in the immediate:false line's callback parameter, to the **init()** function and that fixed the problem:  everything runs smoothly from beginning to end.  Yet, **this is not the way it is supposed to work**.  I still don't know what is going on with that line.

This morning, on my computer at work (behind Active Directory), that fix didn't work.  I have to refresh the page a couple of times so that the script runs from the beginning and the immediate:true triggers recognizing the user's Signed In state and displaying the proper button on screen.

Any ideas on why does this callback fail?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your apiKey in the first section of your code

```
var clientId = '{my client id here}'; // for web
var apiKey = '{my api key here}'
```

Maybe thats the problem.

[Google ApiKeys](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/api-keys)

Comment: Hello, Juan, and many thanks for taking the time to check on my issue.  Actually, I already am defining that in the first section of the code.  Everything runs fine except for that callback function not being called / or the page not acquiring whatever Google's login popup gives it.